# WebView без прокрутки в ios

Tags: ios, webview, прокрутка

Доделываю экран с выводом статей, находящихся на сайте. Хочу сделать вывод статьи, подобно структуре vk.com, т.е. название сверху, само содержимое и снизу комментарии.
Я не понимаю как сделать содержимое статьи на весь экран, а когда прокручиваешь до конца статью, то появляются комментарии.

Я пробовал сделать webview на весь экран, а под ним (за пределами контроллера) комментарии. Но, когда я прокручиваю webview до конца, то я не могу перелистывать ячейки своей таблицы: я нахожусь внутри webView и вижу как двигается только scroll.
Я пробовал отключать scroll, но тогда я не вижу полностью все свою статью (не знаю как сделать авторазмер у webView).

Может кто-то писал подобное или знает выход из ситуации? Буду благодарен любым советам.

Comment: Вот именно по этому в tvOS нет UIWebView.

Comment: у UIWebView есть свойство `.scrollView` с ним можно делать все, что вы можете делать с обычным `UIScrollView`. Например, подписаться на `scrollView:didScroll` и в зависимости от `contentOffset` показывать комментарии или что там вам еще надо.

Comment: или можно отключить все скроллы, и повесть поверх всего контента `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` и, в зависимости от оффсета `UIWebView` либо скроллить статью, либо скроллить весь контейнер чтоб появились комменты.

Comment: Я не совсем понял последовательность:
Поверх UIScrollView я положу webView и растяну его на весь экран, когда я долистаю до конца статьи, как мне отобразить комментарии, вернее где? Просто если расположить форму комментарий ниже webView  на UIScrollView, то я до них не дойду, я буду оставаться в webView. Был бы идеальный вариант, если бы при долистывании статьи до конца я мог блокировать scroll на webView и продолжать скроулить UIScrollView, но тогда возникает проблема листания страницы вверх

Comment: Что то вы два комментария слепили в один. Еще раз вам надо сделать свайп рекогнайзер по всему экрану: либо поверх всего контента положить еще один прозрачный вью и прицепить к нему, либо прицепить отдельно к каждому вью на экране, короче где бы пользователь не потянул у вас на все должен сработать `touchesBegin`. После этого по мере того, как вам приходит `touchesMoved` вы скроллите свой вэбвью; когда он доскраливается до низа, начинаете скролить что там у вас подвигает контейнер с кооментариями на экран.

Comment: Извините, был нетрезв. спорол чушь. никакой swipeRecognizer не надо. А надо сделать сабклассы всех имеющихся view и в них переопределить все методы работы с touch, наследованные от `UIResponder`. В частности `touchesBegan` и так далее (всего 4). а уже дальше делать то, что я написал выше

Comment: Вчера не особо разобрался с этим, сделал просто переход на другой экран с комментариями, но через пару дней обязательно вернусь к этому, спасибо большое за советы